# PHP Efficiency on Mass Calculation

Tags: php, performance

An interesting problem, for a piece of Uni coursework we have been challenged to run a simulation of a server receiving requests and then processing them. I have build and rebuild this multiple times and I think have made it as efficient as I am able, is there anything you can see to improve the efficiency of this program?

The simulation is run for `$simulationLength` and at each `$currentTime` there is a `1/$arrival_rate` chance of a new request arriving. A queue of size `$maxQueueSize` holds these requests and rejects them if the queue is full. For each `$currentTime` a CPU may remove an item from the `$queue` and work on it for `$executionTime` seconds at which point the CPU (server) is removed from the busy queue and is free to work on another request.

My code:

```
<?php

...SNIP error checking...

$queue_size = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : 10000;
$arrival_rate = isset($argv[2]) ? $argv[2] : 3;
$number_of_servers = isset($argv[3]) ? $argv[3] : 2;
$execution_time = isset($argv[4]) ? $argv[4] : 25;

...SNIP error checking...

$simulationLength = 1000000;

$arrivalRate = $arrival_rate;
$executionTime = $execution_time;

$busyServers = array();
$freeServers = $number_of_servers;

$currentTime = 0;
$currentQueueSize = 0;
$maxQueueSize = $queue_size; //Max
$queue = array();

//Stats
$totalRequests = 0;
$rejectedRequests = 0;
$queueSize = array_fill(0, 100, $simulationLength);
$totalWaitingTime = 0;

//while the simulation is running
while($currentTime++ < $simulationLength) {

  //a request has arrived
  if(mt_rand(1, $arrival_rate)==1) {  
    $totalRequests++;

    //Adding to the queue
    if($currentQueueSize < $maxQueueSize) {
      $currentQueueSize++;
      array_push($queue, $currentTime); //add to the end of the queue
    } else {
      $rejectedRequests++;
    }

  } //end request arrived

  //Only one server can fetch requests at a time
  if(!empty($busyServers)&&reset($busyServers) < $currentTime) {
    unset($busyServers[key($busyServers)]); //remove first element - efficient
    $freeServers++; //increase free servers
  }

  //Only one server can fetch requests at a time
  if($currentQueueSize>0&&$freeServers>1) {

    $currentQueueSize--;
    reset($queue); //reset pointer
    $queueTime = $queue[key($queue)]; //read of the front  
    unset($busyServers[key($busyServers)]); //delete off print

    $freeServers--; //use up a server

    $busyServers[] = $currentTime + $executionTime; //mark when free

    $totalWaitingTime += ($currentTime - $queueTime) + $executionTime;
  }

  $queueSize[$currentTime] = $currentQueueSize;
}

printf("Requests served %d\n", $totalRequests);
printf("Rejected requests %d\n", $rejectedRequests);
printf("Total waiting time %d\n", $totalWaitingTime);

printf("Percentage of rejected requests %0.1f\n", $rejectedRequests/$totalRequests);
printf("The average queue size %d\n", array_sum($queueSize)/sizeof($queueSize)); 
printf("Average response time %d\n", $totalWaitingTime/$totalRequests);

?>
```

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Can you use any other language? PHP isn't known for its speed when it comes to numerical operations.

Comment: http://www.phpbench.com - hope that page helps

Comment: If you can't or won't use a different language, perhaps look into [HipHop-PHP](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micro-optimisations but:

- When in a heavy loop like this, --$preIncrement is faster than
  $postIncrement++
- array_push($queue, $currentTime); is a function call
  overhead: use $queue[] = $currentTime; instead
- $currentTime + $executionTime is being calculated twice, calculate it once and store the result, then use that